Raspberry pi pico doesn't detect module using i2c
I have an MS5611 module. Additionally, I have a custom-designed PCB that contains both the MS5611 and BMP280 sensors, which works with an ESP32-WROOM-32D. I want to communicate with the MS5611 module, but my Pico doesn’t detect it. When I removed the ESP32 and connected the Pico to the PCB’s I2C bus, it could detect the BMP280 (0x76) but still couldn’t detect the MS5611 (0x77). However, my ESP32 can detect both barometers on the same I2C bus. To check if the Pico could detect I2C devices, I used the I2C bus scan tool from the Raspberry Pi documentation. I also uploaded the BMP280 example code from the SDK to the Pico, and I confirmed that the sensor works.
My CMakeLists.txt.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)

project(firmware C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

pico_sdk_init()

add_executable(picoProgram
    main.c
    main.h
)

target_link_libraries(picoProgram
        pico_stdlib
        hardware_i2c
        hardware_uart
        hardware_gpio
        )

pico_add_extra_outputs(picoProgram)

pico_enable_stdio_usb(picoProgram 1)
pico_enable_stdio_uart(picoProgram 1)

I used 4.7K resistors instead of 10K ones on the I2C bus, but this didn’t solve the issue. I also tried increasing and decreasing the baud rate, but that didn’t work either. All the sensors are working, as I tested them with the ESP32.
My code: main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hardware/i2c.h"
#include "pico/binary_info.h"
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/gpio.h"
#include "main.h"


#define I2C_PORT i2c0
struct MS5611_CALIBRATION ms5611_calibration;


void ms5611_init()
{
    //ms5611 reset
    uint8_t src;
    uint8_t buffer[2];
    src = MS5611_CMD_RESET;
    sleep_ms(10);
    int a = i2c_write_blocking(I2C_PORT, MS5611_ADDRESS, &src, 1, true);
    sleep_ms(10);
    //READ PROM
    for(int offset = 0; offset < 7; offset++)
    {
        src = MS5611_CMD_READ_PROM + (offset * 2);
        i2c_write_blocking(I2C_PORT, MS5611_ADDRESS, &src, 1, true);
        i2c_read_blocking(I2C_PORT, MS5611_ADDRESS, buffer, 2, false);
        printf("%i, %i, %i\n", offset, buffer[0], buffer[1]);
        ms5611_calibration.C[offset] = buffer[0] << 8 | buffer[1];
        sleep_ms(10);
    }
}
void ms5611_read()
{
    uint8_t D1_G[2] = {MS5611_CMD_D1, MS5611_CMD_READ_CMD};
    uint8_t A[2];
    i2c_write_blocking(I2C_PORT, MS5611_ADDRESS, D1_G, 2, true);
    i2c_read_blocking (I2C_PORT, MS5611_ADDRESS, A, 3, false);
    printf("%i, %i, %i\n", A[0], A[1], A[2]);
    ms5611_calibration.D1 = A[0] << 16 | A[1] << 8 | A[2] ;

    uint8_t D2_G = {MS5611_CMD_D2, MS5611_CMD_READ_CMD};
    uint8_t B[2];
    i2c_write_blocking(I2C_PORT, MS5611_ADDRESS, D2_G, 2, true);
    i2c_read_blocking (I2C_PORT, MS5611_ADDRESS, B, 3, false);
    printf("%i, %i, %i\n", B[0], B[1], B[2]);
    ms5611_calibration.D2 = B[0] << 16 | B[1] << 8 | B[2] ;
}

int main()
{
    stdio_init_all();
    sleep_ms(2000);
    i2c_init(I2C_PORT, 400000);
    gpio_set_function(8, GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_set_function(9, GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_pull_up(8);
    gpio_pull_up(9);
    bi_decl(bi_2pins_with_func(8, 9, GPIO_FUNC_I2C));
    sleep_ms(2000);
    ms5611_init();

    
    while(1)
    {
        ms5611_read();
        printf("#############################");
        printf("\nP: %i\n", ms5611_calibration.P);
        printf("D1: %i\n", ms5611_calibration.D1);
        printf("D2: %i\n", ms5611_calibration.D2);
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}

and main.h
#ifndef __MAIN_H_
#define __MAIN_H_

static int MS5611_ADDRESS        = 0x77;
#define MS5611_CMD_RESET         0x1E
#define MS5611_CMD_READ_CMD      0x00
#define MS5611_CMD_READ_PROM     0xA0
#define MS5611_CMD_D1            0x48
#define MS5611_CMD_D2            0x58
struct MS5611_CALIBRATION
{
    uint16_t C[10];
    uint32_t D1;
    uint32_t D2;
    uint32_t dT;
    uint32_t TEMP;
    uint64_t OFF;
    uint64_t SENS;
    uint32_t P;
};
void ms5611_init();
void ms5611_read();

#endif


Repeating from Staging, do you have an oscilloscope to monitor the SDA line and make sure the I2C looks right?  I2C is somewhat sensitive to signal levels.

İ don't have oscilloscope.
